# Django ORM Count Without Duplicate Column

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I have a table called Reading History. I want to find the average number of reads in this table. I wrote the following method for this, but I can't get the right result. Records are made in the table once (student-book records with the same values). When the same record comes, the `counter` value is increased by one.

For example, suppose that two different students read two different books. I expect `total reads / 2` but the result I get is `total reads / 4` because there are 4 rows in the table. How can I calculate this? For example, if a student reads 4 different books once, the average will be 1, but the average should be 4.

I tried to use distinct and values but I couldn't get the result I wanted. Maybe I didn't manage to use it correctly. Also I tried to use `Avg`. When `avg` didn't give the correct result, I tried to break it down and get the values myself. Normally, `Avg` was written in `Sum`.

**Serializer**

```
class ClassReadingHistoryReportSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    instructor = InstructorForClassSerializer(source="instructor.user")
    students = StudenListReadingHistoryReportSerializer(many=True,
                                          source="student_list_class")
    avg_read_book = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        exclude = [
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "school",
        ]

    def get_avg_read_book(self, obj):
        sum_read_book = Class.objects.filter(id = obj.id).aggregate(sum_read=Sum('student_list_class__child__child_reading_history__counter'))
        count_child_record = Class.objects.filter(id = obj.id).aggregate(count_child=Count('student_list_class__child__child_reading_history'))
        return None
```

**Models**

```
class ChildProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        verbose_name=AccountStrings.ChildProfileStrings.user_verbose_name,
        related_name="user_child")
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        "country.City",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=AccountStrings.ChildProfileStrings.city_verbose_name,
        related_name="city_child_profiles")
    hobbies = models.CharField(
        max_length=500,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=AccountStrings.ChildProfileStrings.hobbies_verbose_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = AccountStrings.ChildProfileStrings.meta_verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = AccountStrings.ChildProfileStrings.meta_verbose_name_plural

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name

    def clean(self) -> None:
        """
        This method will check if the user type is a child during creation.
        """
        if self.user.user_type != 2:
            raise ValidationError(AccountStrings.ChildProfileStrings.user_type_error)

class School(AbstractSchoolBaseModel):
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        "country.City",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name="city_schools",
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.SchoolStrings.city_verbose_name)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.SchoolStrings.name_verbose_name)
    address = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.SchoolStrings.address_verbose_name)
    website = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.SchoolStrings.website_verbose_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = SchoolStrings.SchoolStrings.meta_verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = SchoolStrings.SchoolStrings.meta_verbose_name_plural

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Class(AbstractSchoolBaseModel):
    school = models.ForeignKey(
        "school.School",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="classes_school",
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.school_verbose_name)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.InstructorProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="instructors_school",
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.instructor_verbose_name)
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.name_verbose_name)
    grade = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.grade_verbose_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.meta_verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.meta_verbose_name_plural
        ordering = ["name", "grade"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.school.name} - {self.name} - Grade: {self.grade}"

    def clean(self) -> None:
        """
        This method checks whether the teacher trying to be assigned to the class is working in that school.
        """
        if self.instructor.school != self.school:
            raise ValidationError(SchoolStrings.ClassStrings.instructor_not_working_at_this_school_error)


class StudentList(AbstractSchoolBaseModel):
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(
        "school.Class",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="student_list_class",
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.StudentListStrings.school_class_verbose_name
    )
    child = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.ChildProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="student_list_children",
        verbose_name=SchoolStrings.StudentListStrings.child_verbose_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = SchoolStrings.StudentListStrings.meta_verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = SchoolStrings.StudentListStrings.meta_verbose_name_plural

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.school_class.name} : {self.child.user.first_name} {self.child.user.last_name}"

    def clean(self) -> None:
        result = StudentList.objects.filter(school_class = self.school_class, child = self.child)
        if not self.pk and result.exists():
            raise ValidationError(SchoolStrings.StudentListStrings.child_already_added_to_this_class_error)


class ReadingHistory(AbstractBookBaseModel):
    IS_FINISHED = ((False,
                    BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.is_finished_false),
                   (True, BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.is_finished_true))
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        "book.Book",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="book_reading_history",
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.book_verbose_name)
    child = models.ForeignKey(
        "account.ChildProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="child_reading_history",
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.child_verbose_name)
    is_finished = models.BooleanField(
        choices=IS_FINISHED,
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.is_finished_verbose_name
    )
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.counter_verbose_name,
        default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.meta_verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.meta_verbose_name_plural

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.child.user.first_name} {self.child.user.last_name} - \"{self.book.name}\" "

    def clean(self) -> None:
        result = ReadingHistory.objects.filter(child=self.child,
                                               book=self.book)
        if not self.pk and result.exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                BookStrings.ReadingHistoryStrings.exists_error)
```

I forgot to add the `counter` column in the BookReadingHistory table to the diagram. Diagram and Table data are shown in the images below.

**Table**

[image: Table]

**Diagram**

[image: Diagram]

Comment: A BookReadingHistory row is created for each student and book combination even if the student hasn't read the book? Can you share the Child, Book and BookReadingHistory models?

Comment: @IainShelvington No, this is how it works. When he clicks on the "start reading the book" button on the frontend, the request is thrown and saved as `is_finished = False`. When he clicks the "Finish reading book" button, the request is sent again and that line is updated as `is_finished = True and counter += 1`.

Comment: Ah okay, but those rows where counter = 0 should be excluded from this calculation?

Comment: Instead of showing an (incomplete) ER diagram why don't you simply show the _relevant_ parts of your relevant models...

Comment: @IDKAnythingAboutMe (sum of the counter column / number of unique child_ids) would get you what you want?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat What you say makes more sense, I'm correcting it. Thank you. I just didn't want to be too much code and reduce readability.

Comment: @IainShelvington With such a code, I counted the unique child values and did the operation. Do you think there is a better solution?  `count_child_record = Class.objects.filter(id = obj.id).aggregate(count_child=Count('student_list_class__child__child_reading_history__child', distinct=True))`

Comment: @IDKAnythingAboutMe I was thinking that you could do this all is a single query from the ChildProfile model - `ChildProfile.objects.annotate(read=Sum('child_reading_history__counter')).aggregate(avg=Avg('read'))`. If you can do this in a single query it should perform better

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, it can be. However, the query I wrote filters by class. I calculate the result by taking the records of all students in the class. In the example you gave, wouldn't the results of only 1 person be calculated? I can't bring it by class. In addition, if I do this in ChildSerializer, it makes an extra query on each student data in StudentSerializer. That's why it made more sense to access it directly from StudentList.